# asp.net with sl4 content?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0

We have an app template we've created in asp.net 2.0 that we use for our web apps. It has a header that hosts a couple controls (like a drop down for customer selection) and a language dropdown. It has a footer that's pretty static. In the middle is the content portion of the masterpage. Talk has come up as to whether we can make the content piece in SL4? I'm not sure how the two pieces (apps) would communicate - like for the customer selection changed. Has anyone done anything like this? Or is this just a really bad idea?

thanks!

Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always silverlight app is hosted on a aspx page. In our case it is content portion of the masterpage.

`<div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplicationTestApp.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>`
There are lot of ways ur silverlight app can communicate with our old aspx pages.

Refer : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=170&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1